# Git update-server-info nothing do

Tags: git, repository, dump

**Goal:** hosting git repository on **web** server without git program and git deamon (used HTTP as transfer protocol and dump as git protocol - nothing scripts, nothing shell, only GET supported).

I used tutorial from: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols

**Steps:**

1. Create a new git repo.
2. Clone as --bare to grepo.git
3. call "git update-server-info" in grepo.git (nothing file change!)
4. mv hooks/post-commit.sample hooks/post-commit && chmod a+x hooks/post-commit
5. call "git clone http:// example.com/grepo.git

On client side got: fatal: http:// example.com/grepo.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

On server side in request log: [20/Jun/2013:11:45:16 +0200] "GET /grepo.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 404 1385

Why git call any script on server?
My git version is 1.8.1.5.

Comment: Is the git repository readable by the server process ? Can you provide your web server config ?

Comment: Yes, is readable. For example "curl http://example.com/grepo.git/HEAD" display content of HEAD file (ref: refs/heads/master).

Comment: And I'm sorry. I cannot provide my web server config file, because this is shared web server hosting and I can not access to config file.

Comment: Hmm weird. Is curl example.com/grepo.git/info/refs working (without the ? part). You may double check info/refs permission to see if it's the same as HEAD file.

Comment: Wow! Thanks you! Some file got the wrong group after unpacking the archive (non-existent user). After change the permission of all files, all working fine.

Comment: Great ! I've added an answer and updated your question's title to help future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check repo.git/info/refs permissions to see if it is readable by web server process.